# Language switcher with country code and title

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

For my responsive site i try to override the language switcher block to get both, the long title of the country and the short code. So I can change the display for smartphone or desktop.

I dont know whats the best solution, print a second block or gives out an array with 2 links in a list element. These code overrides only the title.

```
   function mytheme_links__locale_block(&$vars) {
      foreach($vars['links'] as $language => $langInfo) {
        $vars['links'][$language]['title'] = $vars['links'][$language]['language']->language;
      }
      $content = theme_links($vars);
      return $content;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the code of the country or the code of the language (A country can have multiple languages like Canada).

Comment: You have right, i need the code of the language! Sry, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy and paste the entire theme_links function and rename it like
you did `mytheme_links__locale_block`

```
function theme_links__locale_block($vars) {
  $links = $vars['links'];
  $attributes = $vars['attributes'];
  $heading = $vars['heading'];
  global $language_url;
  $output = '';

  if (count($links) > 0) {
    // Treat the heading first if it is present to prepend it to the
    // list of links.
    if (!empty($heading)) {
      if (is_string($heading)) {
        // Prepare the array that will be used when the passed heading
        // is a string.
        $heading = array(
          'text' => $heading,
          // Set the default level of the heading.
          'level' => 'h2',
        );
      }
      $output .= '<' . $heading['level'];
      if (!empty($heading['class'])) {
        $output .= drupal_attributes(array('class' => $heading['class']));
      }
      $output .= '>' . check_plain($heading['text']) . '</' . $heading['level'] . '>';
    }

    $output .= '<ul' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>';

    $num_links = count($links);
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
      $class = array($key);

      // Add first, last and active classes to the list of links to help out themers.
      if ($i == 1) {
        $class[] = 'first';
      }
      if ($i == $num_links) {
        $class[] = 'last';
      }
      if (isset($link['href']) && ($link['href'] == $_GET['q'] || ($link['href'] == '<front>' && drupal_is_front_page()))
         && (empty($link['language']) || $link['language']->language == $language_url->language)) {
        $class[] = 'active';
      }
      $output .= '<li' . drupal_attributes(array('class' => $class)) . '>';

      if (isset($link['href'])) {
        // Pass in $link as $options, they share the same keys.
        $output .= '<div class="desktop-only">';
        // This will give the native name of the lang like 'Français'
        $output .= l($link['language']->native, $link['href'], $link);
        // This will give the name of the lang like 'French' if the website is in English
        // $output .= l($link['language']->name, $link['href'], $link);
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '<div class="mobile-only">';
        $output .= l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link);
        $output .= '</div>';
      }
      elseif (!empty($link['title'])) {
        // Some links are actually not links, but we wrap these in <span> for adding title and class attributes.
        if (empty($link['html'])) {
          $link['title'] = check_plain($link['title']);
        }
        $span_attributes = '';
        if (isset($link['attributes'])) {
          $span_attributes = drupal_attributes($link['attributes']);
        }
        $output .= '<div class="desktop-only">';
        // This will give the native name of the lang like 'Français'
        $output .= '<span' . $span_attributes . '>' . $link['language']->native . '</span>';
        // This will give the name of the lang like 'French' if the website is in English
        // $output .= '<span' . $span_attributes . '>' . $link['language']->name . '</span>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '<div class="mobile-only">';
        $output .= '<span' . $span_attributes . '>' . $link['title'] . '</span>';
        $output .= '</div>';
      }

      $i++;
      $output .= "</li>\n";
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Inside the code you will find the version for mobile and desktop with class added.

```
    $output .= '<div class="desktop-only">';
    // This will give the native name of the lang like 'Français'
    $output .= l($link['language']->native, $link['href'], $link);
    // This will give the name of the lang like 'French' if the website is in English
    // $output .= l($link['language']->name, $link['href'], $link);
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="mobile-only">';
    $output .= l($link['language']->language, $link['href'], $link);
    $output .= '</div>';
```

Then you'll have to hide the link (`display:none;`) in CSS depending on the resolution of you screen (with media queries)

Comment: Great! But i get - "English English Deutsch Deutsch". How could I change to get - "En English De Deutsch"? All the other things works, get the classes and the structure is perfect!

Comment: I edited my answer. Replace $link['title'] by $link['language']->language

Comment: done! very good! Thx to you!

Comment: Happy to be helpful